# How to update multiple comma seperated values in a single column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert

Question on SQL

Suppose there is a table Team_Info which has two columns. One is Team_Name and 2nd is Team_Members. So in this table already data exists.

### Team_Info

Team_Name   ||  Team_Members
Warriors    ||   John

Now I want to add more people in Team_Members columns like I need to add two more people : Alexa and Tony with John

Expected output should be comma seperated like below

### Team_Info

Team_Name   ||  Team_Members
Warriors    ||  John,Alexa,Tony

I am using update query like below but it shows error

1. Update Team_Info set Team_Members='John,Alexa,Tony'
2. Update Team_Info set Team_Members='John;Alexa;Tony'

Likewise I used so many ways but unable to get desired result.

Could anyone please help me on this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do not store a list as a comma delimited string in a column.  it is going to cause a lot of problems. make a new table and store correctly.

Comment: Also "it shows error" tells us nothing. Tell us what the exact error was. Also tag the database you are using

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a many to many relationship right?  a Team can have multiple members and a member can be on multiple teams. so you need 3 tables teams, members, and a teammember junction table.  just google many to many sql relationships

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your syntax error with the information you have provided so I suspect you have mistyped something somewhere.

However, see the comments - this is the wrong way to store your data. Perhaps these code snippets will help.

You need a table to contain the Team and a table to contain the People. You then need a separate table to link the two together.

```
create table #Teams (TeamId int identity(1,1), TeamName nvarchar(50));
create table #Members (MemberId int identity(1,1), MemberName nvarchar(50));
create table #TeamMembers (MemberId int, TeamId int);
```

E.g.

```
-- create your team first
insert into #Teams (TeamName) values ('Warriors');

-- create your people next
insert into #Members (MemberName) values
('John'),('Alexa'),('Tony');

-- Now (and only now) link members to teams
insert into #TeamMembers (MemberId, TeamId) values
(1, 1),(2,1),(3,1)
```

To get your data all reported together start with these joins

```
select t.TeamName, m.MemberName
from #Teams t
join #TeamMembers tm on t.TeamId = tm.TeamId
join #Members m on tm.MemberId = m.MemberId;
```

Things you may need to do your own research for:

- One to Many, Many to Many relationships
- Database normalisation
- If you really want a comma separated list then "sql generate comma separated list"

Comment: wow you really want to go down this road.  what are you going to do when they ask questions like what teams are bob on? or bob has left the organization remove him from all his teams etc.  its going to make for some nasty queries.

Comment: @AnujMinghlani said: "If I say that I have only one table and has 1 column which has one value like 'A'..now I want you to update this column value with A,B,C then how would you do that ?" - Quite simply, I wouldn't. Nor would I employ anyone that did.